# Export data that appears in terminal to Csv file

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, csv

I am getting data to output in the terminal from a json file. I am having some difficulty exporting it to a csv file.

I have a few conditionals in the code to output what info I need. I get the correct output in the terminal. As you can see I have a name, type and value fields output below.

```
apiConfig:orderCommandUrl, String, http://dev.order-service.digital 
apiConfig:orderCommandUrl, String, http://qa.order-service.digital
```

Now I need to export this data to a csv file and I have tried the following:

`$variableData | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation  C:\Users\Temp\Environments.csv`

```
$jsonVariables = Get-Content C:\Users\QVL6\Downloads\express-ordering-web-variables.json | ConvertFrom-Json #| Select -Expand Variables

foreach ($fileEnvironment in $jsonVariables.ScopeValues.Environments) {
    $variableData = $null

    foreach ($fileVariable in $jsonVariables.Variables) {
        if($fileVariable.Scope -ne $null -and $fileVariable.Scope.Environment -ne $null) {
            if($fileEnvironment.Id -eq $fileVariable.Scope.Environment[0]) {
                $variableData += "$($fileVariable.Name), $($fileVariable.Type), $($fileVariable.Description)`n"
            }
         }
    }
        Write-Host $variableData
        $variableData | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation  C:\Users\QVL6\Environments.csv 
}
```

I want to have the data displayed in a csv file with the following headings Name, Type and Description

Comment: You need to either try passing your `$filevariable` directly to `Export-Csv` or generate objects (e.g. with `[PsCustomObject]`) from your data with properties `Name`, `Type` and `Description`, then use `Export-Csv` to output to file.  You are currently creating simple strings with the data and commas included, which is not what is expected by `Export-Csv`.  You _could_ try outputting this to file with `Set-Content`/`Add-Content`, but it's not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$variableData` contains an array of comma-delimited string values, you can do the following:

```
$variableData | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Name,Type,Description |
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation  C:\Users\QVL6\Environments.csv
```

The main issue is not dealing with objects with properties that contain your targeted values. Using `ConvertFrom-Csv`, you can add headers, which become those properties.

Comment: I have tried adding $variabledata to an array and then Export to csv file but it outputs the same value over and over again.

    $dataArray += $variableData



$dataArray | Select @{l='Name';e={$fileVariable.Name}}, @{l='Type'; e={$fileVariable.Type}}, @{l='Value'; e={$fileVariable.Value}}, @{l='Description'; e={$fileVariable.Description}} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation C:\Users\QVL6\Environments.csv

Comment: if `$variableData` is not an array and is a single line per iteration, then use the `-append` switch on `Export-Csv` and call it at the end of the loop.